i have two googlesheets with mulitple tabs, is there a way to cleanly pull all the needed data and track all sheets for accuracy?
I have two google sheets, one sheet has two tabs. The one sheet with two tabs is a master list of people in my organization , the second tab is a copy of the first tab but it tracks what access each member has within the organization. the second sheet is just a contact list made from the first google sheet. the reason it is different only keep members have access to the first sheet but all members of our organization has access to the second sheet. i want to build a system that can check all 3 tabs (across two sheets) for accuracy. so if a new member joins and we input their data into the master list i want to have a way to make sure their information gets transfered to the other two lists as well. i have a somewhat ugly way i am doing it and would like to clean it up.
currently i am running an importrange function from all 3 tabs into one new sheet then i have added a UNIQUE(VSTACK combination that pulls all 3 sheets column A where the names are located. then i created 3 columns titles for each of the lists and do a COUNTIF function where it will show 1's and 0's if that name is found in those sheets. this works but it is in way pretty. is there a better cleaner way?
